# A question about Newton's Divided Difference and continuity of function $f$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, continuity

Recall that Newton's Divided Difference:
$$f[x_0,x_1]=\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0},$$
and
$$f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]=\frac{f[x_1,\ldots,x_n]-f[x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}]}{x_n-x_0},$$
where $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are distinct.

Now I have a question about Newton's Divided Difference and continuity of function $f$. Let $f$ be continuous. Assume that
$$X=\{x=(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\quad\text{s.t.}\quad x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\quad\text{are distinct}\}.$$
 Show that $f(x)=f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is continuous on $X$.

Comment: I would use a different letter for the lastly defined function $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $j=0,\ldots, n$, fix $x_k$ for $k\neq j$ and define $f_j:\Bbb R\setminus\{x_k:k=0,\ldots, n, k\neq j\}\to\Bbb R$ as 
$$f_j(t)=f(x_0,\ldots,x_{j-1},t,x_{j+1},\ldots,x_n)$$

You can easily prove (using induction on $n$) that every $f_j$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can not show what you mentioned. Is it possible that you prove it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me your comments about this solution?           Let $P_{n-1}$ be the polynomial which interpolates the
function $f$ at $x_i$, $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$. So we have
$$f(x)-P_{n-1}(x)=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_{n-1})f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x],$$
where $x\neq x_i$, $i=0,\ldots,n-1$. 

Suppose that $x=x_n$. Since $x_n\neq x_i$, $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, it follows that
$$f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]=\frac{f(x_n)-P_{n-1}(x_n)}{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_n-x_i)}.$$
$f$ and $P_{n-1}$ are continuous and $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_n-x_i)\neq 0$, so $f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

We will prove by induction on $n$.

**Base case:** Assume that $x_0$ is fixed and $g(x)=f[x_0,x]$. But
    $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}.$$
Since $x\neq x_0$ and  $f$ is continuous, it is obvious $g(x)$ is continuous on
$$X=\{(x_0,x)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\quad\text{s.t.}\quad x_0,x\quad\text{are distinct}\}.$$
**Induction step:** Let $n$ be given and suppose  $f(x)=f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is continuous on 
$$X=\{(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\quad\text{s.t.}\quad x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\quad\text{are distinct}\}.$$
Now, assume that $g(x)=f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x]$ where $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are fixed and distinct. But
$$g(x)=\frac{f[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x]-f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]}{x-x_0}.$$
Since $x\neq x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $f[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x]$ is continuous by induction hypothesis, $g(x)$  is continuous too. So
$f(x)=f[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}]$ is continuous on 
$$X=\{(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+2}\quad\text{s.t.}\quad x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}\quad\text{are distinct}\},$$
and the proof of the induction step is complete.

Comment: @ajotatxe, Can you tell me your comments about the above solution?